# Remove contact picture

Tags: contacts

How can I remove a contact's picture?

The only option I'm being given is to replace it with another picture. I added the picture and the contact through my phone.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. I want to remove my ex-wife picture but I cant. I change to a totaly black image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot do it directly on the phone.

You can't neither from the live website and neither from Outlook

Answer (score 4):

The only way now a days is changing to another picture. You can change to a black picture but it looks strange in the list of people hub.

Answer (score 3):

Remove existing contact and create new contact with same details.

Comment: but this will remove call history etc.?

Comment: It wont remove any history from call logs, when you delete a contact, it will be shown as a number in the log and even in the inbox also messages will be shown as received from a number. When you create the contact again, everything will be shown as a contact.

Comment: Seems it is the best and only way right now,